My problem is that I can't send my BTC
I sent a certain amount of BTC from the exchange to my trust wallet. Currently, the wallet shows that I have 0.8 BTC, but when I want to send some from this wallet to other addresses, it keeps showing that my balance is 0.
Trust wallet shows my BTC as inscribed status,

What is the name of the wallet software?

Trust wallet，，，

How many confirmations does the first transaction have according to Blockchain explorers?

The transaction has currently reached 800 confirmations.

If your wallet shows the transaction output as "inscribed" it might not allow you to spend it due to an inscription being associated with it? Really you need to check with your wallet provider though, because this sounds like an issue their FAQ should address.

If you recently received BTC in your Trust Wallet, it's possible that the transaction is still unconfirmed. Bitcoin transactions require a certain number of confirmations before they are considered valid and spendable. During this time, the transaction amount may be displayed in your wallet balance but not available for sending.
Remember to exercise caution and double-check all transaction details before sending funds from your wallet. If you're unsure about any aspect of the process, it's always a good idea to seek advice from trusted sources or professionals in the cryptocurrency space.

op already said it's confirmed + it's a copy paste from chat-gpt giving a vague and unhelpful answer
